# PHP HTML Table Syntax Error

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I am trying to get this data to go into a table so I can view it better on my website and I don't really understand how to combine PHP and HTML and I was getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

I dont know if I combine them wrong so here is my code and tell me if I need to supply more than this line of code:

```
<h2>Featured Event's</h2>
<body>
<table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<?php echo ?><td><?php $eventname ?></td><?php echo?><td><?php $row_id ?></td><?php
```

Comment: you can't echo out like that..its totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do that or do:

```
<td><?php echo $eventname ?></td><td><?php echo $row_id ?></td>
```

Or

```
<?php echo "<td>$eventname</td><td>$row_id</td>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><?php echo $eventname ?></td><td><?php echo $row_id ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace `"` with `?>`.  The `?>` *ends* the PHP context and terminates whichever statement is open. Everything between `<?php` and `?>` needs to be one or more *complete* statements.

Choose either of these:

```
<?php

echo "<td>$eventname</td><td>$row_id</td></tr>"
```

Or

```
<tr>
  <td><?= $eventname ?></td>
  <td><?= $row_id ?></td>
</tr>
```

---

You're also missing an opening `<tr>`, which isn't optional.